# Read CSV into R based on where header begins

Tags: r, csv

I have a large number of CSV files. Some have the header beginning on the first row, others have the header beginning on the 3rd row, others the 7th and so on.

The headers all look the same, they just start on different rows across different files. Is there a way to conditionally read.csv a file to start where the header begins?

For example, if I know the headers all have the first column names "office#", could I somehow instruct R to start reading the csv file when it first runs into the field "office#" and treat that row as the header?

Comment: `fread` from the `data.table` package is pretty good a picking these things up. Otherwise use `readLines` and then `grep` to select the header row - you can then use `skip` in `read.csv`

Answer (score 3):

I have **4 CSV files**:

One table with a header beginning on **row 1** (iris.csv)

[image]

And 3 tables with headers beginning on **rows 3, 1, and 5** (sales_1, sales_2, sales_3)

[image]

As long as I know the **first column names** of each table, I can use the **smart_csv_reader** function to determine where each header begins, and **read each CSV file at the correct row number**:

```
first_columns <- c('sepal.length', 'month', 'month', 'month')

smart_csv_reader <- function(directory) {
    header_begins <- NULL
    file_names <- list.files(directory, pattern=".csv$")
    for(i in 1:length(file_names)) {
        path <- paste(directory, file_names[i], sep='', col='')
        lines_read <- readLines(path, warn=F)
        header_begins[i] <- grep(first_columns[i], lines_read)
    } 
    print('headers detected on rows:')
    print(header_begins)
    l <- list()
    for(i in 1:length(header_begins)) {
        path <- paste(directory, file_names[i], sep='', col='')
        l[i] <- list(read.csv(path, skip=header_begins[i]-1))   
    }
    return(l)
}
```

Just pass in the **directory** where all your CSVs are.

**Usage**:

```
smart_csv_reader('some_csvs/')

[1] "headers detected on rows:"
[1] 1 3 1 5
```

As you can see the function **returns the correct row numbers for each table**. It also **returns a list of each table read correctly**:

[image]